# how to view Jquery file in a readable way?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery file which its entire code is written in a few but very long lines
I have tried to manually divide the code to paragraphs, and mainly enter "new line" character where it is needed, but this is painfully slow and i have come to believe that there must be a better way
please help

[image]

Comment: Use the autoformat-option of your IDE (if your using one which is capable of doing that) or use the format option of chromes dev console.

Comment: Why cant you use online formatter http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Use Sublime editor - https://www.sublimetext.com/
and get PrettyJSON extension.
Using PrettyJson you can, format the jquery.

Comment: this file looks like a minified file, is it  .min.js ?

Comment: Look here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

Comment: thank you, i didn't realize this process is called Formatting, let alone that there are online formatters. THANK YOU @charankumar

Comment: @Ein2012 YES! it actually is a minified file. i didnt realize that the .min extension has a meaning... is that something i should somehow use? is there  a way to UNminifiy the file? is this needed? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the following link to understand [minification](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/glossary/minification.html). You cannot magically get your original file from a minified file (as your function names and variable names has been renamed). If you have downloaded this file try to download un-minified version. If it is in your development machine look for un-minified version. But you can at least beautify your code to understand the code using [unminifyjs](https://unminify.com/). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can Use online formatting tools. Its simple and efficient in case if your editor won't supports formatting also.

[An example here](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: what about the minifying? does that formatter unminify the file automatically?

Comment: it will convert minify file also..for example bootstrap.min.js too it will format, if not try another online site